# How to use validation in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my program, when I click a particular row in DataGridView, if that row contains `"\"` it should pop up an error message that `"\ is not allowed in name or in path"`. I don't know how to do that.

Here is the code:

```
namespace OVF_ImportExport
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string sName = "";
        string sPath = "";
                public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                 sName = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                 sPath = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            }
        }

        private void BtnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("Export.bat");
            file.WriteLine("c: ");
            file.WriteLine("cd \\");
            file.WriteLine("cd Program Files ");
            file.WriteLine("cd VMware");
            file.WriteLine("cd VMware OVF Tool");

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                 sName = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                 sName = sName.Trim();
                 sPath = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

              file.WriteLine("start ovftool.exe --powerOffSource vi://" + TxtUsername.Text + ":" + TxtPassword.Text + "@"
                   + TxtIP.Text + sPath + " " + "\"" + TxtBrowsepath.Text + "\\" +  sName + "\\" + sName + ".ovf" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);



            }
            file.WriteLine("pause");
            MessageBox.Show("Batch File Created","Batch File");
            file.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why would you want to only flag this error on clicking the row? If some data isn't allowed in the row then why not cleanse it of this data before databinding?

Answer (score 2):

try using this:

```
// Attach DataGridView events to the corresponding event handlers.      
 this.dataGridView1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValidating);
```

method for  above event handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
        DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Validate the CompanyName entry by disallowing empty strings.
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CompanyName")
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
                    "Company Name must not be empty";
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```